# Jmeter + Chrome driver config: empty page while processing

Tags: performance, google-chrome, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I configured jmeter to run tests using Chrome Driver Config.
Test run with no errors:

```
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/06/01 20:14:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/06/01 20:14:16 INFO  - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig: iterationStart() 
2015/06/01 20:14:43 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/06/01 20:14:43 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/06/01 20:14:44 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/06/01 20:14:44 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

But within the execution i see empty page only: http://screencast.com/t/REd78GizooEl

What can be the reason?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved the problem, by adjusting preferences (can't remember clear steps)